# Reshape 3D Tensor before Dense layer

Tags: tensorflow

Given a tensor of `shape=[batch_size, max_time, 128]` (the output of an RNN), for which `max_time` may vary, I would like to apply a fully connected layer to project the data onto a `[batch_size, max_time, 10]` shape.

The question is: do I need to reshape the input Tensor first, merging the first two dimensions, then apply tf.layers.dense, then reshape back to 3D? Or can I simply use tf.layers.dense on the 3D tensor to obtain an equivalent effect ?

I would like to have a single weight matrix shared for all the connections between the 128 RNN units and the 10 output classes, allowing at the same a variable length `max_time` for each batch.

Comment: I know this is old, but thanks for asking this! Helped me a lot

Answer (score 4):

After further investigation, is appears that the two options are equivalent.

The Dense.call() method checks the number of dimensions. If this is larger than 2, then it computes a tensordot (an operation which corresponds to numpy.tensordot) between the input and the weights, choosing as axes the last dimension in the input and the first dimension in the weights. Otherwise it applies standard matrix multiplication (matmul).

[Source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/python/layers/core.py#L134)